# Chrome google certificate with deep inspection

Tags: firewall, google-chrome, deep-packet-inspection

I enabled deepinspection from my firewall for HTTPS connections using a company root CA.
It is well working for all sites and browsers but I found a strange behaviour by Google Chrome.

When I open google site using Chrome, the certificate is still issued by google. When I open all other sites, the certificate is issued by my localCA.

If I open Google site with all other browsers (Firefox, IE) the certificate is issued by my localCA as expected.

How can Google Chrome application bypass deepinspection for google site only?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome official builds pin public certificates of Google properties. I think this overrides the usual behavior of private trust anchors. I don't know of a way to change this behavior in the official builds.

To test this is the case, try other similar browsers, perhaps Chromium or the new Chromium-based Edge. (Pinning could break stuff permanently, so it is only good for the auto-updating Chrome, and for 10 weeks after build date.)